# How to only use the second or third callback

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Not sure if this is a stupid question but is there a cleaner looking way to only utilise the second/third callback when a function is called?

```
    uploadTask.on('state_change', ()=>{}, ()=> {}, () => {
        updateCampsite(newCampsiteRef.id, data)
    })
```

Here I only want to use the third call back but it won't work without the empty functions before it. Is there a better way? Or should I not do this at all?

TIA!

Comment: You could probably pass `undefined` instead of empty functions. Whether this is "cleaner" depends on you. Also, it depends on whether whatever API you're using allows it. Likely it does but it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: impossible to say with confidence without knowing the implementation in `uploadTask()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass undefined instead of the empty functions. However, if that gives any error, then pass empty functions. It would be alright even then also.

```
uploadTask.on('state_change', undefined, undefined, () => {
    updateCampsite(newCampsiteRef.id, data)
})
```